# Python dictionary appending key:value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
import ast # needed to read text as a dictionary
import operator # needed to find term with maximum value
def define_words():
    final_dict={}
    with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/experimental_dict.txt','r', encoding = "utf-8") as dic:
        dante_dict = ast.literal_eval(dic.read())# reads text as a dictionary
        print('the start length was: ', len(dante_dict)) # start length of source dictionary

        key_to_find = max(dante_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
        print('The next word to define is ', key_to_find) # show which word needs defining

        definition = input('Definition ? : ') # prompt for definition
        for key in dante_dict.keys():
            if key == key_to_find:
                final_dict.update({key_to_find:definition})
        dante_dict.pop(key_to_find)             
        print('the end length is : ' ,len(dante_dict)) 
        print(dante_dict) # print source dictionary, modified
        print(final_dict) # print dictionary with newly defined entry

    with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/experimental_dict.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as outfile:
        outfile.write(str(dante_dict)) # writes source dictionary minus newly-defined term

    with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/trial_dictionary.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as finalfile:
        finalfile.write(str(final_dict))
```

I apologise for reposting a similar question in response to the help that I have had. Don't know how to add the modifications on. I still have a problem with this. My final dictionary is overwritten each time instead of appending the newly defined term, so the dictionary only contains the last key:value pair.I thought that by using dict_name[key] = value, the new entry would be appended leaving other entries intact. Help appreciated

Comment: Use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to store dictionaries or any object into a file and to do the reverse.

Comment: You create a *new* dictionary every time you call your function; did you expect the dictionary to retain previous keys from previous calls to the function?

Comment: Yes, I did expect that. How do I get around this problem, please

Comment: @user1478335 Could you give me a text file to work with, I'd like to totally recreate your problem.

Comment: Games Brainiac, thank you. How do I get a text file to you? Simply the text in and edit of my question or is there some way to append a text file? Here is a small version:{'amico   ': 1, "'Segnor": 1, 'volgere': 1, 'spaventate,': 1, "s'avvantaggia": 1, 'livore': 1, 'disposta   ': 1, 'pennelli': 1, 'atto': 15, 'Berti': 1, 'atti': 7, 'Gaia    ': 1, 'alzato,': 1, 'reda': 2, "d'ossa": 1, 'rede': 1, 'compartir': 1, 'calle': 2, 'dogliose': 1, 'consiglia,': 1, 'piacere,': 2, 'saglia    ': 1, "l'ampiezza": 2, "d'Acquasparta,": 1,'solvesi': 1, 'Dopo': 3, 'amico,': 1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a "final_dict" dictionary with one single "key_to_find" key on each function call. I understand (reading the comments) that you expect your function to retain the results of its previous calls, and append the new result.

The function's namespace is destroyed with all the variables in it when the function returns. However, you can save your existing dictionary with simply rearranging your code into two functions:

```
def collectDict():

     # first initialize your final_dict and dante_dict dictionary
     final_dict={}
     with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/experimental_dict.txt','r', encoding = "utf-8") as dic:
             dante_dict = ast.literal_eval(dic.read())# reads text as a dictionary


     # loop as many times you want:
     (dante_dict,final_dict) = define_words(dante_dict,final_dict)    # call the define_words function to update your dictionaries


     # write your dictionaries

     with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/experimental_dict.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as outfile:
             outfile.write(str(dante_dict)) # writes source dictionary minus newly-defined term

     with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/trial_dictionary.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as finalfile:
             finalfile.write(str(final_dict)) 



 def define_words(dante_dict,final_dict):
      # your already written function without the initialization (first 3 lines) and file writing part

      return(dante_dict,final_dict)  # you return the dictionaries for the other function
```

This is a straighforward solution, but note that [classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) are designed exactly for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. I shall try to implement this later today

Comment: I have tried your solution which works very well, except that in my implementation it still overwrites the final dictionary so that there is always only one entry, the latest to have been modified. Di I use pickle to solve this?

Comment: I am making a meal of this. I finally clicked that I needed to use 'a' and not 'w'!! Stupid Boy that I am! However even this I can't seem to do properly: I now get ('word1':'definition1'}{'word2':'definition2'}{'word3':'definition3'}{... }. How do I get {'word1':'def1', 'word2':'def2',…} ?

Comment: Did you remove the line `final_dict={}` from your define_words function?